# Feature request: append text of Contact Us submission when sending auto-response

Tags: feature-request, support, feedback, contact, content

When I clicked on "Contact Us" in the Meta.SE footer, I got an automated response with a ticket number in the subject line.  The body of the email said

> (date)
>
> This is an automated message to confirm that we have received your
>   request at our Stack Overflow community support portal. While we
>   strive to respond to everyone within 24 hours, the nature of community
>   tickets sometimes means longer wait times and we cannot guarantee any
>   response time.
>
> If your question is concerning our Talent or Teams products, we will
>   make sure your request to forwarded to the correct team as soon as
>   possible.
>
> Thank you for your patience, and we'll respond as soon as we can.
>
> - Stack Overflow Support Team

It would be helpful if the automated response would include the contents of the input box where I poured my heart out, appended to the standard blurb.

In my limited experience with web programming, I found this to be straightforward to implement.

Comment: I don't understand the number of downvote as from the standpoint of the ticket writer it is indeed quite annoying not to have any way to access the ticket they wrote.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - It's hard to argue with the answer by animuson.  I personally would think it would not be a huge deal to either check that it's a valid email, or else provide a button that would pull up the logged-in user's ticket history (including text of ticket).

Answer (score 8):

We cannot do this.

Because we don't validate the email address being typed into the box, sending the message back allows someone to utilize our contact form as a method of spamming other users by typing their email address and then typing whatever they want into the box. By only allowing *us* to see it at first, we limit that damage.

The original message should be quoted when we *reply* to the ticket, unless someone messed up sending the reply.

---

Incorporated from comment: We don't have a reliable way to validate the email. It would require a lot of development work to directly integrate into our support software, and even then it's only useful for email addresses currently verified to your account, and does nothing for unregistered users.

Comment: Thank you.  Would it be difficult to validate the address?  I use the address to log into the site! // Is emailing support@stackoverflow.com or team@stackoverflow.com equivalent to using the "Contact Us" button?  That would give me the date and text of my message. // By the way, if I used "Contact Us" on Nov. 6, got no answer, tried again on Nov. 17, and still got no answer, would it help if I tried a third time?

Comment: We don't have a reliable way to validate the email. It would require a lot of development work to directly integrate into our support software, and even then it's only useful for email addresses *currently* verified to your account, and does nothing for unregistered users.

Comment: Thank you for explaining.  // Is emailing support@stackoverflow.com or team@stackoverflow.com equivalent to using the "Contact Us" button? That would give me the date and text of my message. // By the way, if I used "Contact Us" on Nov. 6, got no answer, tried again on Nov. 17, and still got no answer, would it help if I tried a third time?

Comment: I can tell you, though, that your tickets are awaiting replies. It's just a matter of getting to them, which sending more tickets doesn't help. So unless you have new information to add, submitting another won't really do anything. And yes, emailing directly triggers the exact same (or possibly more vague) message.

Comment: animuson -- thank you, that is very helpful.  (The second one I sent added new information.) // Is emailing support@stackoverflow.com or team@stackoverflow.com equivalent to using the "Contact Us" button? That would give me the date and text of my message.

Comment: (feeling quite discouraged....) When you have a chance, could you respond to the question in my last comment, please?

Comment: @aparente001 Is there something further that's not answered in your [follow-up question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339845/compare-methods-of-contacting-the-cm-team)?

Comment: Thanks for asking.  Sorry, I just noticed *yes, emailing directly triggers the exact same (or possibly more vague) message.*  So you did answer that question.  (Although I don't know why you said "(or possibly more vague)."  // I feel ever more dejected about not ever having had a response to my "Contact Us" missives... and it's been so many months now -- I do remember the general thrust of my messages, but it would be soo helpful to have the original, complete text, ALONG WITH A SUBSTANTIVE RESPONSE....