# Compare methods of contacting the CM team

Tags: support, contact, community-managers

In relation to [Feature request: append text of Contact Us submission when sending auto-response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339002/287826):

Is emailing support@stackoverflow.com or team@stackoverflow.com equivalent to using the "Contact Us" button?

I am asking because I wonder whether emailing one of those addresses might function as a work-around.

Is there any difference between emailing support@stackoverflow.com vs. emailing team@stackoverflow.com?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Emailing team@ will end up in exactly the same queue with exactly the same message. It is just an alias that we no longer use for outgoing email, so you'll never see us reply back with it (which can sometimes mess up your email chain depending on your client, causing the reply to start a new chain).

The support@ email, though, is a catch-all email for "we don't know which product you're trying to reach out about" - it still doesn't send any additional information, but the auto-response doesn't make assumptions about the product and is much more vague. It's generally a less effective way of contacting about commumity support issues because it has to go through an extra triage step before ending up in the correct queue.

If you'd like to email us directly so that you can keep the original message in your inbox, email to ***community-support@stackoverflow.com*** as the **preferred avenue for community support issues**.

For reference, here's a more straight-forward breakdown of the email addresses we follow:

- community-support@stackoverflow.com for community support issues, automatically fed into the correct queue

  - team@stackoverflow.com is an alias
  - community@stackoverflow.com is an alias
- If you are a user of our paid product, you can open a ticket on [our support portal](https://stackoverflow.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/26).

You may see some places where the same email addresses are referred to with an @stackexchange.com address. These are aliases for the equivalent @stackoverflow.com addresses.

All the community-related options on the contact us form email to community-support@ when submitted.

Comment: Is this a valid email: community-support@stackexchange.com? Also, please check this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369725

Comment: @RandomPerson That link no longer works.

Comment: @Tsundoku The post was deleted. If you wanna see it, check this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4bFk.jpg