# As of August 2023, is community-support@stackoverflow.com still an active email address for reaching out to the SE Team?

Tags: support, moderation, contact, community-managers

I am trying to reach out to the SE team regarding a site [moderation issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/162827), but my message text exceeds the contact form’s 5000-character limit. According to this 2019 post, "[Compare methods of contacting the CM team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339846/162827)", sending an email to community-support@stackoverflow.com will also reach the SE team. But after emailing them yesterday, Aug. 25, I got no response or acknowledgment. When I used the contact form in 2019, I got an automated reply with a ticket number. Is this still the case or not?

> This is an automated message to confirm that we have received your request at our Stack Overflow community support portal. While we strive to respond to everyone within 24 hours, the nature of community tickets sometimes means longer wait times and we cannot guarantee any response time.

Is community-support@stackoverflow.com still active as of August 2023? If not, what is the current email address for the SE team?

Comment: I'm not going to answer officially, as I'm not a CM, and I'm not going to raise alerts and ping people on a weekend, but I don't know if you should expect the exact same behavior between the form (as it was implemented in 2019) and sending a direct e-mail (in 2023). I'm not sure if a direct e-mail even triggers an auto-response, but if it did, it's quite possible it ended up in spam/junk etc. Anyway, as far as I know, yes, that should still be a valid e-mail.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an appropriate way to do it... but why didn't try filling the form twice? In the first form fill the starting details and in the second form, mention that it's continuation of your previous tickets. I think the CMs can group the tickets together and analyse your ticket.

Comment: "But after emailing them **yesterday, Aug. 25**, I got no response or acknowledgment." hmm... maybe wait for a week for a response from CMs?

Comment: @RandomPerson "*wait for a week for a response from CMs?*" When I last used the contact form, I received an automated reply with a ticket no., so I expected the same thing this time. I’d rather not wait a week only to discover that the email address is inactive and that my message went nowhere. However, I now know that the email address is still active, as animuson (SE staff) confirmed in their answer to my question. "*try filling the form twice*" I’m also not sure if that’s appropriate (maybe that’s a question for another post), since the system might split my messages among different people.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yea, it still works.

We generally don't retire emails. If we ever decide to change it to something else, we prefer to redirect old ones to the new one due to them being plastered all over Meta etc. Even our old team@ emails still work and redirect to the current community-support@ inbox.

We currently do not send ticket created notifications for community support tickets, for either contact form submissions or direct emails. (I know I probably have a dozen answers at this point teetering back and forth on whether we do this or not... But this time, it's probably going to stay off.)

Comment: That’s helpful to know. Thanks. A week ago, I emailed community-support@stackoverflow.com, but they still haven't replied to me, so I just attempted to get in touch with the CMs again through the contact form and divided my message into parts. This time, I got an automated reply about the support team not handling support tickets on weekends but that they'd reach out as soon as they could on the next business day.

Comment: @galacticninja It is a 4-day holiday weekend for US employees so there is a special message set up to alert people.