# Why are Freshdesk tickets deleted after they've been closed for a year?

Tags: discussion, contact

I read on [this animuson's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343083/178179):

> However, we do use Freshdesk, which has a separate portal with ticket viewing capabilities. We don't explicitly support this, which is why the login options are hidden in the portal, but if you can manage to get yourself [logged in](https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/login) using the same email address you used to contact us, you can view your correspondence for the past year there (we delete tickets out of Freshdesk after they've been closed for a year). Last I checked, only the Google option allowed you to login to the portal without being a support agent - but I haven't checked in a while.

This is great to have access to tickets somewhere, but why are Freshdesk  tickets deleted after they've been closed for a year? That'd be convenient to store them forever or at least a few years for archival purposes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I see the content of tickets I raised on the Stack Overflow community support portal (https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343080/where-can-i-see-the-content-of-tickets-i-raised-on-the-stack-overflow-community)

Comment: @curious Not a duplicate. The same author posted that question a few hours before this one; this is a follow-up question from the answer received on that question.

Comment: In the meantime this has been answered by an edit to the answer on the previous question.

Comment: @Tufkamt Closing this question as a duplicate now would effectlvely penalize the author for something that was perfectly OK at the time they asked it. I'd recommend posting an answer saying "animuson commented on the answer to your previous question" and a quote of said comment.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Just wanted to let users know who'd like to answer.

Answer (score 9):

[animuson's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343083/178179):

> They are deleted because of GDPR. They contain private information that we don't wanna keep sitting around indefinitely, and it's too difficult to incorporate it into the process for when we receive requests via the form, so we just make sure they're eventually deleted always.