# How do I track the status of a ticket I lodged over the contact form?

Tags: support, contact

A couple of weeks ago I used the contact form that the sites have, but I have not received any response. Is there a way to see the status of that ticket, since they give a 6 digit number but I haven't found where to use it to track the open ticket?

the ticket was opened on the site in Spanish contact form.

**Update:**

Well, after 15 days, I have not had any contact on ticket 117005:

[image]

How long does it take to respond to a ticket?
My ticket does not appear associated with my email or account used to send it.
Could it be that the trust & safety team went on vacation?

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296310/contact-us-and-then-what), but things might have changed since then.

Comment: This [answer about Freshdesk](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343083/323179) might be accurate since I think they switched back to it. Though I think the answer to your question is ultimately that there's a backlog.

Comment: I have verified that answers, and it is not what I am looking for... send me something about OS teams and I am looking for something about the tickers that I personally open in the contact form.

Comment: Could you add the detail that the ticket is in Spanish to the question - it seems that it could make a substantial difference.

Answer (score 2):

I think nowadays you can:

1. go to https://support.stackenterprise.co/support/tickets
2. log in with the email you used to send the request via the "Contact Us" form
3. click on the "Tickets" button on the navbar

Then you should be able to see a list of your open tickets. The ticket number should match the number included in the receipt email you received from the Stack Exchange site after submitting the Contact form.

I don't think the status of the tickets receives significant updates, unless Staff responds to it or closes it. But you can keep track of those changes.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have done what you suggest step by step and there are no open tickets.

Comment: The ticket might have been closed then. Or you logged with a different email. It could also be that the support portal shows only Stack Overflow tickets but I’m not sure.

Comment: What if this was generated on the site in Spanish?

Comment: Ah then I have no idea if there’s a separated ticketing portal for non-English inquiries

Comment: It says my account is not recognized. I *think* that's the domain for Enterprise customers with tickets, not for regular SE/SO users with tickets.